# Binding child ember objects to handlebars class

Tags: binding, ember.js, handlebars.js

Having a binding issue with a child object of an ember.view object.  Code is as follows:

--Textbox class extended from Ember.TextField

```
App.TextBox = Ember.TextField.extend({
attributeBindings:['placeholder', 'autocorrect','autocapitalize'],
value:null,
isInvalid:true,
validate:function(){
    this.set('isInvalid', false);
    return false;
},
focusOut:function(event){
    this.validate();
}});
```

---View that uses App.Textbox

```
App.ViewTextBox = Ember.View.extend({
name:"viewName",
label:"View Label",
input: App.TextBox.extend({
    placeholder:function(){
        return this.get('parentView').get('label');
    }.property('label').cacheable()
})});
```

--Handlebars with bindings

```
{{#view App.ViewTextBox}}
{{label}}<br/>
{{#view input valueBinding="parentView.value"}}
   <div {{bindAttr class="isInvalid"}}></div> 
{{/view}}{{/view}}
```

Issue is this:
1) After the initial rendering of the view, the class is properly set, but subsequent changes to the isInvalid value, through the onFocusOut call, do not change the class in the DOM.  Ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You can't use a `view` block helper with Ember.TextField.

Comment: I have the same problem without a textfield, I'm quite sure that's a bug or not intended to work.